# Moduli stacks of ($\mu$-)semistable sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

$X$: smooth projective surface/$\mathbb{C}$
$H$: ample divisor

Then, is the moduli stack of (Gieseker)semistable sheaves for $H$ with a fixed Chern class dense in the moduli stack of $\mu$-semistable sheaves for $H$ with the Chern class?

(I am especially interested in the case $\rho(X)=1$ & rank $2$ semistable sheaves.)

Thank you !